# Ubuntu fails to boot on a dualboot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I started up Ubuntu and everything went fine till it locked up, so I restarted the tower, and upon reboot, I selected Ubuntu from Window's bootloader, but the boot failed with an error message and refused to boot Ubuntu but opened Grub.  I clicked the tab entered boot and it said kernel is missing.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the exact error messages?

Comment: Was Ubuntu installed from inside Windows using WUBI.EXE?

Answer (score -2):

Need more information.
You mention BIOS but Windows 8. Is this really a Windows 8 system with UEFI or a system you manually installed yourself so Windows 8 may be in BIOS boot mode?

How did you shutdown Ubuntu? Forcing it down may corrupt file system and need a fsck or Windows may need chkdsk from your Windows repairCD*

From liveCD so everything is unmounted,swap off if necessary, change example shown with partition sdb1 to your partition(s)
e2fsck is used to check the ext2/ext3/ext4 family of file systems. -p trys fixes where response not required

```
sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sdb1
```

if errors: -y auto answers yes for fixes needing response, also see man e2fsck

```
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is really just a comment to the question. The latter part is just shot in the dark because there's no information that a filesystem in an inconsistent state is the cause of this. Moreover, how does this fix a missing kernel as described in the question?